# How to make clickable item on listview and what adapter should i choose?

Tags: android, listview

this is the script :

```
public class LecturAct extends ListActivity {

    private static final String AR_ID = "id_lec";
    private static final String AR_LC = "lec_nm";
    private static final String AR_CLS = "class";
    private static final String EXTRA_DATA = "idr";
    JSONArray lec = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lec_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lec);

        Intent quiz = getIntent();
        String id = quiz.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA);

        String link_url = "http://xxxx/xxxx.php?id="+id;

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.gtJson(link_url);

        try {
            lec = json.getJSONArray("lec");

            for(int i = 0; i < lec.length(); i++){
                JSONObject ar =lec.getJSONObject(i);

                String lectid = ar.getString(AR_ID);
                String lecname = ar.getString(AR_LC);
                String class = ar.getString(AR_CLS);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(AR_ID, lectid);
                map.put(AR_LC, lecname);
                map.put(AR_CLS, class);

                lec_list.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.adapter_listview();
    }
```

ive tried to make a clickable item on my listview, this is the script:

```
public void adapter_listview() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, lec_list,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { AR_ID, AR_CLS, AR_LC}, new int[] {
                        R.id.title, R.id.content, R.id.code});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                String cd = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code)).getText().toString();
                Intent in = new Intent(LecturAct.this, Quis.class);
                in.putExtra(AR_ID, cd);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
```

but when i click an item, it keep take me to the wrong direction, always take me to the last item. if the items on the list are

1. physic
2. biology
3. sport
4. social
5. math

then when i click biology or whatever i choose, it will always lead me to the "math" page. so what should i do? am i using a wrong adapter? please help me, give me solution to make this right :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is like Amin's but with few differences. Sample code:

```
@Override 
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String mlecture p = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
...
    in.putExtra(AR_ID, lecture);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Notes:

- Get the **ListView parameter (l)**, and get the row/item **position** to begin with.
- You cannot use view.findViewById method since ListView (l) already has the UI object.
- Use the override onListItemClick since ListActivity is used.

Comment: i can't use onListItemClick, the red hint keep telling me to change it  to onItemClick

Comment: I am glad it works now for you. (I should have responded earlier) Actually onItemClick is not available when ListActivity is used. onItemClick is available when you're using Activity instead. If so, then "lv.setOnItemClickListener" is used. This framework design makes it hard to change the parent class from Activity to ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Just override `protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` in `LecturAct` for example

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String cd = getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(LecturAct.this, Quis.class);
    in.putExtra(AR_ID, cd);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Comment: `String cd = getListAdapter().getItem(position);' what sould i do with this? i've tried to change it but i dont understand :(

Answer (score 0):

> My example like yours.Just change your object casting.Or String.

```
catalogListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  Object obj=(Object)((String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));
            String ss=obj.toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PdfReader.class);
                i.putExtra("catalogPdfUrl", "" +ss;
                getActivity().startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: this line `PDF pdf = (PDF) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);` i dont understand how to change it :(

Comment: PDF is myListItem custom  Object.Your object is String.String is extend (java lang.object)Same build.

Comment: ive tried to change it : `String cd = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);` but its still automatically choose the last item on the list

Comment: its should be complete

Comment: And i asked to you working examples provided in the
@The Original Android answers

Comment: this line `Object obj=(Object)((String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                  String ss=obj.toString();` what should i do with this? the logcat shows error at this line. or would u mind to implement my script to your answer?

Comment: My offer.You make an custom object and add in object field hasMap.After add list your custom object.And you should make custom adapter.(If you want a example.I share to with you). so be resolved because you will give object from custom adapter.If this example is not work i will try make an example

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code more closely. I suspect the data is not arranged correctly.

Change FROM:

```
new String[] { AR_ID, AR_CLS, AR_LC},
new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.content, R.id.code});
```

TO:

```
new String[] { AR_ID, AR_CLS, AR_LC},
new int[] { R.id.code, R.id.title, R.id.content });
```

I switched **R.id.code**. I think this is compatible with in.putExtra(**AR_ID**, cd). There is no good way for me to make sure since I don't know Quiz.class.

Comment: Quiz.class just retrieve the extra data and set them as TextView